# Adding support for pprof for C#

Tags: c#, stack-trace, profiler

Google has this great CPU profiler called pprof. It works by taking timely screenshots of all threads call stack. The frequency of each method call tells how much time was spent in each method.

Pprof tool has a very simple file format. All that's required to make it work for C# is a fast call stack screenshoting mechanism.

What's the fastest way of taking a screenshot of all threads stack trace in C#?